# How to post Json string in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ios7

I'm getting an error while posting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Please help me.

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:infoDictionary
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


    NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://My url"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

Comment: check this textfile in this text file all method of sending data on server using json.http://pastie.org/8497421#

Comment: before post try to search on google.plenty of answer available on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting any parameter name into the JSON you are passing.

```
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:infoDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


                NSString *saveString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME=%@",saveString];
                NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];


                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://My url"]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

                [request setHTTPBody:postData];
                NSURLResponse *response;
                NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
                NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use [Restkit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) to do this stuff. After you set it up, you can post an object in one line of code.

Comment: I'm very new to this Technology Please help me step by step to do usin rest kit

Comment: This is a step by step tutorial: https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md